# How to decide between module_exists and function_exists?

Tags: 7

I'm familiar with using `module_exists` in a module, and using it in situations like:

- Enable some extra functionality in a module, provided some other module is available in the site also. The [Reservations: Email](https://www.drupal.org/project/reservations_email) module contains an example (actually there are plenty of examples of this), as shown in its [module source](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/reservations_email/tree/reservations_email.module#n86): to use tokens (in the eMail body) requires that the [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module is enabled.
- Implement module dependencies in a theme, as shown in the answer to "[How to implement module dependencies in a theme and package modules with a theme?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164748/how-to-implement-module-dependencies-in-a-theme-and-package-modules-with-a-theme/164751#164751)".

However, there is also `function_exists`, such as shown in the answer to "[Is it possible to declare a Javascript library dependency at Hook.info?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208776/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-javascript-library-dependency-at-hook-info/208975#208975)".

I have the impression that using `function_exists` is a more robust (safe) approach as compared to `module_exists`. Especially if you want to be sure that some function (added in a newer version of a module) is available, whereas by just using `module_exists`, you risk to run into errors like those:

- if a site is ***still*** using an ***old*** version of a module, which doesn't have that function ***yet*** (so you shouldn't try to use it  ***yet***).
- if a site is ***already*** using an ***new*** version of a module, which doesn't have that function ***anymore*** (so you shouldn't try to use it  ***anymore***).

**My question**: what are the typical criteria, or pros/cons, to decide for using either  `module_exists` versus `function_exists`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prior 3 (interesting) answers appear to me as somehow confirming my "perception" (as I described in my question). Interestingly enough, those answers were originally written independent from each other (they were posted at more or less the very same moment, as illustrated in the [timeline of this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/209335/timeline), use the "toggle format" to see "mins").

[Jimmy Ko](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/56904)'s answer (+ comments below it), illustrates some more examples of how using `function_exists` can make a module more robust with respect to possible changes in some other module that a module uses (depends on).

[Clive's](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800) answer shows you could as well combine `module_exists` and `function_exists`, while the comment below it resolved my doubts about my `function_exists` example (ie it should rather use `module_exists`).

[mpdonadio](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/835)'s answer (+comments below it) is, at least to me, the toughest to digest. But after reviewing [Shawn Conn](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/45675)'s comment below it, I found a few more links that provide more details about all this, i.e.:

- [Program to an interface, not an implementation](http://www.fatagnus.com/program-to-an-interface-not-an-implementation/).
- From SO: [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).
- From programmers.SE: [Understanding "programming to an interface"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/232359/understanding-programming-to-an-interface).

**"My conclusion"** (after digesting the previous answers): Leave it to Drupal core to use `function_exists`, and contributed/custom modules should try, as much as possible, to stick to `module_exists` ... though there are exceptions ...

Answer (score 13):

You should always program to the API and not the implementation.  If Drupal provides a mechanism to do something, use it.

`module_exists()` should almost always be used for soft dependencies on something provided by a Drupal module.  You can always get version info, and decide what to do, using `system_get_info()`.  There have been cases where functions are available when modules have been disabled (some of the class autoloader modules have has this problem).

`function_exists()` should be reserved for checking whether a PHP feature or library is available.  Core has some examples of this in some of the `drupal_` wrappers for string manipulation and character set conversion.

Answer (score 10):

`module_exists` is a Drupal API function used to determine whether a module is *installed*, it isn't designed to give any guarantees of the functionality a module might contain, including what functions it declares.

`function_exists` is a PHP core function which literally determines whether a function with a given name exists in the current request.

As such, they aren't really comparable with one another, you use them for different things. In fact it would be easy, albeit potentially redundant, for them to complement one another, e.g.

```
// Do something with a specific module 
if (module_exists('foo')) {
  // Check what's available 
  if (function_exists('foo_bar')) {
    // ...
  }
  elseif (function_exists('foo_baz')) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree ***they aren't really comparable with one another***

Comment: Do you mean the library module check in `MODULENAME_requirements` in the linked post? Yes, that would make more sense as a call to `module_exists`. As MPD mentioned, the higher-level/more abstracted way to ensure that a dependancy has certain functionality is to examine the code for a release, and make your code rely on a specific version that you know your code works with. Just like Composer/NPM/Bundler/etc do it

Answer (score 4):

You are right, `function_exists` is a more robust way to check the existence of the API function provided by contrib module. It is very suitable for directly using the contrib module's API.

I use [Session Cache API](https://www.drupal.org/project/session_cache) as an example:

```php
if (function_exists('session_cache_set')) {
  session_cache_set($bin, $data)
}
```

However, some contrib modules only provides some extra properties or feature, it is very hard to say which dependent function is. In this case, you need to use `module_exists`

I use [Elements](https://www.drupal.org/project/elements) as an example:

```php
if (module_exists('elements')) {
  $form['url'] = array(
    '#type' => 'urlfield',
    // other code
  );
}
else {
  $form['url'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    // other code
  );
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I'll need some more time to "digest" ...

Comment: How would you know whether `session_cache_set` is being provided by https://www.drupal.org/project/session_cache or another module, and therefore does what you want?

Comment: @MPD It depends on if you believe in everyone using the same naming strategy as suggested. `function_exists` can prevent undefined function error when the contrib module did change its API after update. Of course, the most guarantee method is wrap `function_exists` with `module_exits` as @Clive mentioned, but, to me, it is too tedious.

Comment: @MPD Theoretically, replying interface is a better approach, and I would love to follow. But in practical, `function_exits` indeed prevent the site from completely brokering down...